# Git folder merge between branches

Tags: git-merge

I have 2 branches

1. master

   |
    _ folder1

   |
    _ folder2
2. releases

   |
    _ folder1

   |
    _ folder2

Both have the same folder structure.

How can I merge only 1 folder from master branch to release branch, say folder1

Comment: Git manages changesets, not folders. Are, in your case, all changes to folder1 independent of changes to folder2?

Comment: yes folder1 changes are independent. When releasing to the releases branch we dont want to merge folder2 changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussion in the comments I assume two things:

- Changes in `folder1`and `folder2` are independent.
- There are only changes on the master branch (at least to `folder1`).

Subsequently, the following instructions will overwrite any changes made to folder1 on the release branch. They basically copy the files in `folder1` over from `master` to `release`.

Check out the `release` branch.

```
git checkout release
```

Then, checkout all files in folder1 from the master branch. Doing so, leaves `release` the checked out branch. Also, all those file get added to the staging index.

```
git checkout master -- folder1
```

Commit the changes.

```
git commit -m "Copy over changed files in folder1 from master branch."
```

Answer (score 0):

Since changes to both folders are independent, the git way would have been to keep the changes in two separate branches, instead of commiting them to the one master branch. That would allow you to merge in just one of the branches.

Now, how can you get that state of two branches?
You will need the commit from that on the changes were developed, i.e. the last commit that was merged into releases. Use `git log` to find the commit id. This should be a commit on the master branch. Then create a tag there:

```
git checkout <commit id>
git tag begin_of_new_development
```

Checkout the master branch and create a new, checked out branch `f1`:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b f1
```

Then use interactive rebase on the new branch to remove the commits that are not relevant to `folder_1`:

```
git rebase -i begin_of_new_development
```

From the list, remove all commits that don't work on `folder_1`.

You should now be left with a branch `f1` that you can merge into you `release` branch. If you do the same for folder_2, you can later merge that changes into release, too. Be warned, however, to never leave one commit in both `f1` and `f2`, because rebasing gives them new commit ids, and thus git can not know that they contain the same changes. Also, you can't merge `master` into `release` any more.

Comment: I was expecting of a much easier way to do it... the way how we see the diff between branches within a folder

say go to folder1 & execute the below
`git diff --name-status master..releases --relative`

it will display the difference of that folder alone. Wanted to merge these changes in an easier way

Comment: Using diff, you only get to see the differences, ignoring where they came from, i.e. if they were development in the master branch or changes in the release branch. I didn't think this was what you were going for, but if you just want the release branch to be like the master, that of cause is much easier.